# How to optimise aggregation query to group based on different keys?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping, aggregation

My mongoDB Document looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {
        "name": "f1",
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "field_2": {
        "name": "f2",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "field_3": {},
      "field_4": {
        "name": "f4",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "field_1": {
        "name": "f1",
        "second": {
          "check": false
        }
      },
      "field_2": {
        "name": "f2",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        },
        "first": {
          "check": true
        }
      },
      "field_3": {
        "name": "f3",
        "second": {
          "check": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

1. Create parent groups f1(`fields.field1.name`) and f2(`fields.field2.name`)
2. Each of them again have two child groups which shows metrics based on the below conditions
   respective to their parent groups:

   1. first_group: count of documents with `first.check=true`
   2. second_group: count of documents where `first.check` is not present AND `second.check=true`

Result:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "f1",
        "values": [
          {     
            "second_group": 0,
            "first_group": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": "f2",
        "values": [
          {
            "second_group": 1,
            "first_group": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have generated the query using $facet, but I'm not satisfied as I have to repeat my logic for child level grouping in each of the parent group(I have 4 arrays in $facet)

[My Query in Mongo Playground attached here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JCg_x8gkwWg)

Please tell me how to remove repeating queries.
Is there any other method to achieve this use case?

Thanks!

Comment: Basis expected O/p and looking at conditions made this [play query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T0OxbEwApbV). See if that helps and what u are looking for.

Comment: Although I need $facet for some parallel operations(my actual use case is more complicated), this is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much @ambianBeing

Comment: Posted that as an answer. Consider accepting it. And glad this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the aggregation query which should work for the given conditions and expected O/p:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$fields",
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $objectToArray: "$fields",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data",
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.v.first.check": true,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$data.v.name",
      values: {
        $push: {
          first_group: {
            $sum: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$data.v.first.check", true],
                },
                1,
                0,
              ],
            },
          },
          second_group: {
            $sum: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $eq: ["$data.v.second.check", true],
                },
                1,
                0,
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

[Play link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T0OxbEwApbV)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative solution:**

We normalize `fields` attribute and calculate `first_group` and `second_group` values with the [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) operator to `Integer` with this [behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#converting-to-an-integer).

```
Input Type  Behavior
---------------------
Boolean     Returns 0 for false.
            Returns 1 for true.
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      fields: {
        $map: {
          input: [
            "$fields.field_1",
            "$fields.field_2"
          ],
          as: "field",
          in: {
            _id: "$$field.name",
            first_group: {
              $convert: {
                input: "$$field.first.check",
                to: 16,
                onNull: 0
              }
            },
            second_group: {
              $convert: {
                input: {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $type: "$$field.first.check"
                        },
                        "missing"
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$field.second.check"
                  ]
                },
                to: 16,
                onNull: 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$fields"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$fields._id",
      first_group: {
        $sum: "$fields.first_group"
      },
      second_group: {
        $sum: "$fields.second_group"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id",
          values: [
            {
              first_group: "$first_group",
              second_group: "$second_group"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A_n5k_J_JDS)